# copyright of teaching (in video) learned coding techniques

Tags: copyright

I'm having a hard time finding what the copyright law would be on teaching others through videos, what I've learned from professors in college. How does copyright apply to such a thing? Can I make a video of me writing out what I've learned, or should I change the material completely?

Even if I change it, isn't it still considered getting the information from my previous instructors? And possibly copyright infringement?

But if so, then pretty much every bit of code that any one has ever learned was learned from some source, and if they teach any thing in a video, it's copyright infringement. So I'm very confused on this topic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Information" can't be copyrighted. The particular expression or form can (and usually is, and then usually automatically) but regardless of where I learned a fact, I can write it again in my own words however and whenever I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facts are not subject to copyright. If you're teaching physics, Newton's Laws are not the subject  of copyright law. Now, a teacher explaining Newton's laws may have made some illustrative pictures - those *are* protected. While these pictures may illustrate facts, it's not the subject matter but the creativity in their drawing which grants them protection under copyright law.

So, in general, if you have mastered your field well enough that you can explain the field yourself, without reusing the text, pictures or other protected works of your professors, then you will be the sole owner of the copyright on your video's. (And if you can't really explain it yourself, you should be studying instead of teaching).